# MacOS crashed four times today

Tags: memory, kernel-panic

#### Further information: unable to get into diagnostics

I tried getting to Apple Diagnostics: shut down computer, press power button, hold D key down: instead of diagnostics I am taken to the usual login screen. According to Apple's site: (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) I should try using Option D. Again, takes me to the login screen not the diagnostics. Not sure what my next step is.

#### Original problem: Kernel Panic

Can anyone help me interpret this? Commenters suggested I try apple diagnostic mode, but see above, I am not able to get there. Here's the dump.

```
Anonymous UUID:       BBE62DAE-7B75-1109-3481-33104AF1985D

Sun Feb 12 19:59:40 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80139fcc5d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f956e0681, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff8243e9c260, CR3: 0x00000000043bc000, CR4: 0x0000000000002660
RAX: 0x000000000008fff7, RBX: 0x0000000000000002, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000001
RSP: 0xffffff826b0fb9e0, RBP: 0xffffff826b0fba10, RSI: 0x000000000000ffff, RDI: 0xffffff82177d1000
R8:  0xffffff80539a0804, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff80539a0608, R11: 0xffffff7f956dbcb6
R12: 0x2a09060d30210102, R13: 0x000000000000ffff, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0xffffff82177d1000
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f956e0681, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff8243e9c260, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff823fd46c50 : 0xffffff80138


Model: MacPro5,1, BootROM MP51.007F.B03, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.66 GHz, 20 GB, SMC 1.39f5
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: DIMM 1, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 2, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 3, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31384A53463235363732415A2D3147314431
Memory Module: DIMM 4, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31384A53463235363732415A2D3147314431
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.4f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Ethernet 2, Ethernet, en1
PCI Card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, Display Controller, Slot-1
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVD-RW GH41N
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD6400AAKS-41H2B0, 640.14 GB
Serial ATA Device: OCZ-VERTEX2 3.5, 115.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: OWC Mercury Electra 3G SSD, 480.1 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Mass Storage Device
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: CTH-460
USB Device: Apple LED Cinema Display
USB Device: Display iSight
USB Device: Display Audio
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: officejet 5500 series
USB Device: Fitbit Base Station
USB Device: Miscellaneous Device
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Have you tried identifying any potential hardware issues using the Apple Hardware Test? Boot your Mac while holding the D key to start the Apple Hardware Test. From there, you can scan your Mac for hardware issues which might be causing these frequent kernel panics.

Comment: Ah good idea, I didn't know about it. I was blaming it on the new MacOs beta that I just installed but from he trace can you guess if it's a hardware or software problem?

Comment: Turn Mac off, turn it on, hold D down. Takes me to login screen! Then according to Apple site, try holding Option D down. Takes me to login screen. In other words, it's not getting me to diagnostics.

Comment: First thing I'd do is remove any 3rd party kexts. They're not listed in your panic report so I can't see which you have. btw, is that a 4,1 with the firmware update?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, to run AHT, you need to boot it off of Disk 2 of the Install Disks.  The Mac Pro 2010 and 2012 came with 10.6 and 10.7 respectively.